# Can I use mean and standard deviation to spot outliers?

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

I have a list of measured numbers (e. g. lengths of products).  Of these I can easily compute the mean and the standard deviation.

Now, when a new measured number arrives, I'd like to tell the probability that this number is of this list or that this number is an outlier which does not belong to this list.  Is this statement possible given only mean and stddev?

Can I compute the probability with which this new value is part of the list?  I'd like to have a probability as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. It is a known fact that for a sufficiently long **list** , (denoting mean by $\mu$ and standard deviation by $\sigma$) the range $[\mu-3\sigma,\mu+3\sigma]$ encompasses about (more than) [$99.73\%$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) of the data points, so if the new value is out of this range then it is $99.7\%$sure to be out of the **list**

You can somewhat use the concept of [$p-value$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) here. (Assuming the new value to follow gaussian distribution,since we don't know) ; find out the value of $\Phi(x)$--(CDF of $N(\mu,\sigma^2)|_{x=\text{new value}}$) Its $p-value=1-\Phi(x).$ If $p-value\lt $ some confidence level(say 0.05) then you can consider it within the **list** else not.

Comment: Ok, I should have worded more concrete:  Can I compute the probability with which this new value is part of the list?  I'd like to have a probability as a result.

Comment: @Alfe I said so; that if the new value  is within the range given then $P($it will belong to the list$)<1$. Google and you will find a derivation of how $99\%$ comes into play

Comment: @Alfe Take a look at the link

Comment: I took.  So I think I need to compute Φ((v - μ) / σ), can you confirm this?  I found that Φ(x) is not part of typical math computer libraries, but `erf(x)` is, and that Φ(x) = (1 + erf(x / sqrt(2))) / 2 .  So the answer should be: p(v) = abs(Φ((v - μ) / σ) - Φ((μ - v) / σ)).  Can you confirm this?

Comment: I correct myself: p(v) = (1-Φ(abs(v - μ) / σ)) * 2

Comment: @Alfe You can approach that way$(\Phi({v-\mu\over \sigma}))$. A better and more practical way is given in the answer. Please upvote and accept if my answer is helpful

Comment: @Qwerty: you're assuming the numbers are Normally distributed (and independent). [chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) gives a weaker, but more general, result.

Comment: @BenBolker Anyway I had to compromise between generality and strength. Since the values are **extremely** real life and random, so its quite often useful to assume Normal distribution since it gives stronger results..(Note: my answer is very specific to this particular problem which the OP has asked)

Comment: I think this Answer much of the discussion of it are off topic: The original Questions speaks of 'computing' the mean and SD. To me this must mean the _sample_ mean and SD. Here we seem to be dealing with the  _population_ mean and SD.

Comment: @BruceET But I mentioned _for a sufficiently **long** list_

Comment: given that this is posted to Mathematics, it feels to me like answers should err on the side of greater rigor ... the question might be better on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: In any case, you should certainly state your assumptions and the basis for them ...

Answer (score 1):

It is best to use a boxplot to find outliers. The problem with
using the sample mean $\bar X$ and the sample SD $S$ is that
an outlier seriously affects the values of $\bar X$ and $S$.

By contrast, the boxplot uses the median and the interquartile
range to detect outliers. These measures of location and
dispersion, respectively, are not much affected by outliers.

If you feel you must use $\bar X$ and $S$, then here is how
to test observations one at a time for outliers: Omit the
suspected outlier. Find $\bar X^*$ and $S^*$ from the
remaining $n - 1$ observations. Then see if the omitted
point is in some interval such as $(\bar X* - 2.5S^*, \bar X* - 2.5S^*)$. If so, the suspected observation is not judged an outlier.
If outside the interval, then consider it an outlier. 
The disadvantage of this method is that you have to
recompute $\bar X^*$ and $S^*$ afresh for each suspected outlier.

Comment: Yeah, well, in my usecase I need to _characterize_ each of a large quantity of such lists with as little data as possible.  Later then come values which are to be checked for fitting into their list or being a sign of an outlier.  It seemed feasible to not store the complete lists but just their mean and SD.  Your suggestion (omitting one point and computing the S again etc.) is (sadly) besides my situation.  But thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use your Standard Deviation to tell you this. Think about what Standard Deviation is telling you.

Comment: Ok, I should have worded more concrete:  Can I compute the probability with which this new value is part of the list?  I'd like to have a probability as a result.